# How to Display Point from Form

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript

For the last few days I have been trying to come up with a way to display a point on a map from a coordinate pair entered into a form.  I began with the sample below and then added the formToJSON Dijit.  Both components seem to be working but I can't figure out how to "hook" them together.

Does any one have any ideas or am I going about this all wrong?

Links to the original sample, my edits and code are below.

Original Sample:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/map/map_topo_graphics.html

dojo.formToJson
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/formToJson.html

My Edits:
http://geoville.org/viewers/DP/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title> Display Point</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.1/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      map{
        padding:0;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
      dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
      dojo.require("esri.map");

      var map, formJson;

      function init() {
        var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-13044922,"ymin":4033097,"xmax":-13042340,"ymax":4034363,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
        map = new esri.Map("map",{extent:initExtent});
        //Add the topographic layer to the map. View the ArcGIS Online site for services http://arcgisonline/home/search.html?t=content&f=typekeywords:service    
        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(basemap);
      }

      function drawPoint(){
        var infoSymbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("i_about.png",30,30);

       //add from the form below.

       var point1 = new esri.Graphic({
        "geometry": 
            formJson,
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 102100
            }

       });
       point1.setSymbol(infoSymbol);

       map.graphics.add(point1);
      }

      function resizeMap(){
        //resize the map when the browser resizes - view the 'Resizing and repositioning the map' section in 
        //the following help topic for more details http://help.esri.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/inside_guidelines.htm
        var resizeTimer;
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout( function() {
          map.resize();
          map.reposition();
        }, 500);
      }
      //Use the formToJson digit to grab the coordinates and convert them to JSON.
      // http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/formToJson.html
      function convertFormDigits() {
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId("convertFormDigits"), "onClick", function() {
            var formJson = dojo.formToJson("myform2");

            //Attach it into the dom as pretty-printed text.
            dojo.byId("formObject2").innerHTML = formJson;
        });
    }

    dojo.addOnLoad(convertFormDigits);


      dojo.addOnLoad(init);
    </script>
  </head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false" style="width:100%; height:80%;">
    <div id="map" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="border:solid 2px #587498;margin:5px;" region="center">
    </div>
    </div>
    <form id="myform2">
    <input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="X" value="-13043577">
    <input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" name="Y" value="4034040">
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="drawPoint()" id="convertFormDigits"> Create Point </button>
    </form>
    <pre id="formObject2"> </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little code that will add a graphic:

```
map.graphics.add(
    new esri.Graphic(
        new esri.geometry.Point(-13043739, 4033623, map.spatialReference), 
        new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol()
    )
);
```

One problem is that dojo.formToJson() returns a JSON *string*. I would ditch this approach and just grab the values out of your text boxes using a simpler method like giving each box and ID and using dojo.byId('boxId').value and parseInt or parseFloat to get a value you can pass to esri.geometry.Point().

Comment: Thanks Derek.  I was hoping the dojo.formToJson would skip a few steps but it may have been making things worse.  Between @GuillaumeC and your help maybe I will finally figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along these lines:

- Get your X and Y elements (getelementbyid).
- Check that their values are numeric and in the correct range.
- If so, create a point (new esri.geometry.Point).
- Convert it to a graphic (new esri.Graphic)
- And add it to the map (map.graphics.add)